Optimizing Sequelize Synchronization Time with PostgreSQL in NestJS
I'm working on a project using NestJS and Sequelize with a PostgreSQL database. My setup includes around 85 tables, and I've noticed that setting synchronize: true in Sequelize takes about 45 minutes to sync the database. This is quite a long time, and I'm looking for ways to optimize and shorten the synchronization process.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any tips on how to speed up the synchronization? Are there best practices or configurations in Sequelize or PostgreSQL that could help with this?
Thanks in advance for your suggestions and insights!
I tried setting the synchronize option to true in Sequelize to automatically sync the database schema with my models. I was expecting this process to be relatively quick, considering the number of tables and associations. However, it takes around 45 minutes to complete, which is much longer than anticipated.

I definitely recommend to use migrations instead of sync method, especially for production environment
